# React Router - 404 page always showing due to custom route component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a component which takes in similar props to the standard react-router `Route` and returns a route. This returned route has a render prop which just passes through the component but adds a nav component. This custom `NavRoute` does not work with the react-router `Switch` component, as when I use the custom component inside the switch along with a catch-all 404 page, the page always shows.

How can I make the 404 component only show if none of the other routes match the url?

NavRoute

```js
const NavRoute = ({ exact, path, component: Component }) => {
  return (
    <Route exact={exact} path={path} render={(props) => (
      <div style={styleSideNav}>
        <Nav />
        <Component {...props} />
      </div>
    )}/>
  );
});
```

Usage

```js
  <Switch>
    <NavRoute exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <NavRoute exact path="/about" component={About} />
    <Route path="/" component={Page404} />
  </Switch>
```

**EDIT:**
Codesandbox of full example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-stack-overflow-5jcum
Url of codesandobx: https://5jcum.csb.app/invite/abc

Comment: I tried your code on [codepen](https://codepen.io/wbh24/pen/GRpqpaJ?editors=0010) and it seems to be working for me. Maybe I am misunderstanding what you are trying to do?

Comment: Hmm. I tried to simplify my code so it wasn't too long but I can put a full example on codepen now.

Comment: Check edit in main post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Switch only works with the first level of components directly under it. It can't traverse the entire tree.**

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5785#issuecomment-351067856

To fix that, we can pass array of routes instead of routes wrapped in fragment. I have made the changes and updated in codesandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-stack-overflow-hu62w?file=/src/App.js

Comment: That hid the 404 message on the /invite/:inviteID route, but it also hid it on /asvdyuasidhn

Comment: @BenjaminSommer I found a solution and updated in the answers.